# Django 1.7 (apparently) not running migrations on manage.py test

Tags: python, django, migration, django-1.7, django-migrations

Working on a Django 1.7 project, I've had the need to add a field to an existing model.

I added the following:  `bairro = models.CharField(max_length=200)`

Then I ran both commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

And now, tests won't run anymore. 
Whenever I run `python manage.py test` it gives this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column admin_starbeli_salao.bairro does not exist
```

Which is strange, since if I open the shell I can add objects and the field does work.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you post the model in which you have added the field?

Comment: @Ymartin I found the problem, added an answer explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem in one of the migrations.

To find what it was, I dropped my db and tried to run `python manage.py migrate`, but the same error ocurred.
Then I noticed one the related models had a default for this model, like this:

```
def first_my_model():
    return MyModel.objects.first().pk if MyModel.objects.first() else 0
```

It was trying to use that newly added (and not yet existing on the db) field on this call, thus throwing the error.